# PHP SQL syntax error for insert into

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I have a bunch of php files corresponding to an application I am writing, using MySQL for my database structure. I know this questions has been asked before but I've been through most of the posts about it and can't find something that will help...

In my PHP file I have a SQL query

`$group_sql = "INSERT INTO group (name, description, ownerEmail) VALUES ('$groupName', '$descrip', '$owner')";`

that corresponds to a group table with three attributes: name, description, and owner email. $groupName, $descrip, $owner are three variables I have defined. I'm getting this syntax error when I try to run the query:

> Error: INSERT INTO group(name, description, ownerEmail) VALUES(hi, hi, test@example.com)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group(name, description, ownerEmail) VALUES(hi, hi, test@example.com)' at line 1

Can someone please help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: group is a reserved word backrick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [**MySQL reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you name a table that, then you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
$group_sql = "INSERT INTO `group` (name, description, ownerEmail)  
              VALUES ('$groupName', '$descrip', '$owner')";
```

Notice where SQL starts with the error and points to it?

```
>for the right syntax to use near 'group  
>                                 ^
```

---

- This applies to both tables and columns.
- Consult: **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Comment: group is the name of my table, not column. does this still apply?

Comment: @Monj I've fixed the wording. Yes, it's the same thing. Tables and/or columns alike.

Comment: Yes. This applies to table and column identifiers.

Comment: `Another happy ending`